# Can't make an object move. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used a YouTube tutorial for this. I don't get why it doesn't work. For some reason nothing happens when I press `A` or `D`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #container{
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    width: 400px;
    outline: 2px solid black;
    }
    #character{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;   
    width: 50px;
    outline: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #FF6600;
    left: 0;
    }
</style>
<body onkeydown="anim">
<div id="container">
    <div id="character"></div>
</div>  
<script>
    var container = document.getElemnetById('container');
    var character = document.getElemnetById('character');
    var characterLeft = 0;
    function anim(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 97){
            characterLeft += 2;
            character.style.left = characterLeft + 'px';
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 100){
            characterLeft -= 2;
            character.style.left = characterLeft + 'px';
        }
    }
</script>
</body> 
</head>
</html>
```

`

Comment: You've got a typo, it should be `document.getElementById("")` instead of `document.getElemnetById("")`

Comment: Oh, thanks. Still doesn't work though :(

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div id="pop" onclick="anim();">
<span>click me</span>
<div id="container">
    <div id="character">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var container = document.getElemnetById('container');
    var character = document.getElemnetById('character');
    var characterLeft = 0;
    function anim()
    {
        alert('yes it work!!');

        if (e.keyCode == 97){
            characterLeft += 2;
            character.style.left = characterLeft + 'px';
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 100){
            characterLeft -= 2;
            character.style.left = characterLeft + 'px';
        }
    }

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Why? This works as well as OP's code. Also, a key hit is required, not a click.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I also swapped the key effects - pressing "a" moves the box to the left and pressing "d" moves it to the right. Hope this helps. Gav

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #container
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 600px;
            width: 400px;
            outline: 2px solid black;
        }

        #character
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: 50px;   
            width: 50px;
            outline: 2px solid black;
            background-color: #FF6600;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="character"></div>
        </div>  

    <script>
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        var character = document.getElementById('character');
        var characterLeft = 0;

        document.onkeypress = function (e) { 
        e = e || window.event; 
        var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
            if (charCode == 97){
                characterLeft -= 2;
                character.style.left = characterLeft + 'px';
            };
            if (charCode == 100){
                characterLeft += 2;
                character.style.left = characterLeft + 'px';
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body> 
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: no worries. Just a thought - you could choose other keys and their values and then move the box up and down as well as side to side.